# Pyspark - Check if a column exists for a specific record

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark 3.1.1 and python 3.8

I have a json file in input like this:

```
{"id" :1, "field_a": "test"}
{"id" :2, "field_a": "test", "field_b": "z"}
{"id" :3, "field_a": "test", "field_b": null}
```

When I try to read the file using spark, it automatically fills the missing column `field_b` for the first record to `null`.

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .getOrCreate()


df = spark.read.json('my_file.json').show()
```

Will return:

```
+-------+-------+---+
|field_a|field_b| id|
+-------+-------+---+
|   test|   null|  1|
|   test|      z|  2|
|   test|   null|  3|
+-------+-------+---+
```

In this way I cannot distinguish the records that have `NULL` as a value and those that don't have the field at all.

I know that is possible to check if a column exists using `df.columns` but that will return the columns of the entire dataframe so it doesn't help me.

I want a function like this:

```
df = df.withColumn("column_in_json", record_has_column(field_b))
```

with an output like this:

```
+-------+-------+---+--------------+
|field_a|field_b| id|column_in_json|
+-------+-------+---+--------------+
|   test|   null|  1|         false|
|   test|      z|  2|          true|
|   test|   null|  3|          true|
+-------+-------+---+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json.html#pyspark-sql-dataframereader-json), when we are reading the json file and not providing the schema it will first look into the data and identify the schema. So once you read the json, rows with no specific fields in json file data, must have a null value for those fields.

I hope following snippet can be helpful to identify the fields with null value in original json

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T
>>> import json
>>> schema = spark.read.json('test.json').schema
>>> df = spark.read.text('test.json')
>>> null_fields_udf = F.UserDefinedFunction(lambda value: [key for key,value in json.loads(value).items() if value is None], T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
>>> df = df.withColumn('fields_with_null', null_fields_udf(df.value))

>>> df = df.withColumn("value", F.from_json(df.value, schema))
>>> df = df.select("fields_with_null", "value.*")
>>> df.show()

+----------------+-------+-------+---+
|fields_with_null|field_a|field_b| id|
+----------------+-------+-------+---+
|              []|   test|   null|  1|
|              []|   test|      z|  2|
|       [field_b]|   test|   null|  3|
+----------------+-------+-------+---+

>>> 
>>> 
>>> column_names = [col for col in df.columns if col != "fields_with_null"]
>>> column_names
['field_a', 'field_b', 'id']
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for col in column_names:
...     df = df.withColumn("%s_was_null" % col, F.array_contains(df.fields_with_null, col))
... 
>>> df.show()
+----------------+-------+-------+---+----------------+----------------+-----------+
|fields_with_null|field_a|field_b| id|field_a_was_null|field_b_was_null|id_was_null|
+----------------+-------+-------+---+----------------+----------------+-----------+
|              []|   test|   null|  1|           false|           false|      false|
|              []|   test|      z|  2|           false|           false|      false|
|       [field_b]|   test|   null|  3|           false|            true|      false|
+----------------+-------+-------+---+----------------+----------------+-----------+

>>> df = df.drop(df.fields_with_null)
>>> df.show()
+-------+-------+---+----------------+----------------+-----------+
|field_a|field_b| id|field_a_was_null|field_b_was_null|id_was_null|
+-------+-------+---+----------------+----------------+-----------+
|   test|   null|  1|           false|           false|      false|
|   test|      z|  2|           false|           false|      false|
|   test|   null|  3|           false|            true|      false|
+-------+-------+---+----------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `when-otherwise` to check against `field_b` being `null` & get the intended results. Examples can be found [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-when-otherwise/)

#### Data Preparation

```
sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame([
        ('test',None,1),
        ('test','z',2),
        ('test','null',3)
        ],
    ['field_a','field_b','id']
)

sparkDF.show()

+-------+-------+---+
|field_a|field_b| id|
+-------+-------+---+
|   test|   null|  1|
|   test|      z|  2|
|   test|   null|  3|
+-------+-------+---+
```

#### When - Otherwise

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('column_in_json',F.when(F.col('field_b').isNotNull(),True).otherwise(False))

sparkDF.show()

+-------+-------+---+--------------+
|field_a|field_b| id|column_in_json|
+-------+-------+---+--------------+
|   test|   null|  1|         false|
|   test|      z|  2|          true|
|   test|   null|  3|          true|
+-------+-------+---+--------------+
```

Comment: I'm aware of the When Otherwise statement but your solution doesn't resolve the issue. Is only working because you create the Dataframe with None as value. If you read the json as I provided in the example your solution doesn't work